# My for loop doesn't count values from another column in dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm completely lost why my for loop doesn't append the value from another column.

My dataframe looks like this

[image]

and my code is like this

```
i = -1
open_line = []

for line in df["line 1"]:
    idx = i + 1
    if (0 < line < 1000 and df.iloc[idx]["line 2"] < 0):
        open_line.append(df.iloc[idx]["line 2"])
    elif line == 1000 and df.iloc[idx]["line 2"] == 1000:
        open_line.append("NAN")
    elif line == 1000 and 0 < df.iloc[idx]["line 2"] < 1000:
        open_line.append("NAN")
    elif line < 0:
        open_line.append(line)
```

When I print open_line I get

```
['NAN', 'NAN', -1]
```

The problem is when first if statement is passed at row 3 it doesn't append -9 to my list but it just goes on.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that `idx` is never incremented.

Replace:

- `i = -1` with `idx = -1`
- and `idx = i + 1` with `idx = idx + 1`

Then `print(open_line)` outputs `['NAN', 'NAN', -9, -1, -3, -3]`

A more efficient way to do it would be like this:

```py
df.loc[(df["line 1"] > 0) & (df["line 1"] < 1_000), "open_line"] = df.loc[
    (df["line 1"] > 0) & (df["line 1"] < 1_000), "line 2"
]
df.loc[
    (df["line 1"] == 1_000) & (df["line 2"] > 0) & (df["line 2"] <= 1_000), "open_line"
] = "NAN"
df.loc[df["line 1"] < 0, "open_line"] = df.loc[df["line 1"] < 0, "line 1"]

open_line = [i if isinstance(i, str) else int(i) for i in df["open_line"]]
```

Then `print(open_line)` outputs `['NAN', 'NAN', -9, -1, -3, -3]`